# DbContext is just schema or schema and records of my db in memory

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I know about lazy and eager loading, it mean ADO.NET doesn't connect to db until it was necessery for data, so when i  call .ToList() or Iterate on a LINQ query, it connect and retrieve data.

**Db Context in EF is just know about schema of Data base and give me ability to work with db as object and LINQ   OR know about schema AND my records are actually in my memory ?**

I think it is not resonable or even possible i have all records in memory!

another question is **how much is the overload of a DbContext** on memory or for server? it mean just one DbContext is enough or one dbContext has overload for memory ,need split it. is here relation between DDD and spliting DbContext.

Could you direct me to a link to understand?

```
 public class Db : IdentityDbContext<User>
{

    //content
    public DbSet<UrlEntity> ContentUrls { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Banner> Banners { get; set; }

    //item
    public DbSet<ItemCat> ItemCats { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemImage> ItemImages { get; set; }

   // lots of other
}
```

Comment: Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#3

Comment: tnx fro answer, Domain Driven development

Comment: Not sure how it relates to DDD... If you're looking for the concept, consider the DbContext to be bound to a single Session or Unit-of-Work.

Answer (score 1):

DbContext is Schema and Cache. And it will keep track of the object state of objects loaded before and it will slow down over time. I've personally come to find that it's a good thing to use a DbContext for a limited amount of time, like a Unit-of-work or a Request-Response.

See:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#3

There are additional reasons, especially around error handling, why keeping the same context around can cause unexpected behavior:

> Here are some general guidelines when deciding on the lifetime of the context:
>
> When working with long-running context consider the following:
>
> - As you load more objects and their references into memory, the memory consumption of the context may increase rapidly. This may cause performance issues.
>
>   - Remember to dispose of the context when it is no longer required.
>   - If an exception causes the context to be in an unrecoverable state, the whole application may terminate.
>   - The chances of running into concurrency-related issues increase as the gap between the time when the data is queried and updated grows.
> - When working with Web applications, use a *context instance per request*.
> - When working with Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) or Windows Forms, use a *context instance per form*. This lets you use change-tracking functionality that context provides.

See:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx